# Drive API v3 Java/Android - list files sharedWithMe

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I need my app to upload files, on the GDrive account, that can be listed and read by other user accounts (same app, other devices)

I am uploading files from aUserFileCreator@gmail.com and set the permission to anyone/reader + make it public with allowFileDiscovery

```
File file = driveService.files()
        .create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
        .setFields("id")
        .setSupportsAllDrives(true)
        .setIgnoreDefaultVisibility(true)
        .execute();


Permission p = new Permission();
p.setType("anyone");
p.setRole("reader");
p.setAllowFileDiscovery(true);
driveService.permissions()
        .create(file.getId(), p)
        .execute();
```

Share the file later with TheUserToListAndRead@gmail.com

```
Permission accessPermission = new Permission();
accessPermission.setEmailAddress("TheUserToListAndRead@gmail.com");
accessPermission.setType("user");
accessPermission.setRole("reader");
driveService.permissions().create(fileId, accessPermission).execute();
```

When trying to list the files, like below, I am not getting anything back
but the files are visible in the Drive app of TheUserToListAndRead@gmail.com

```
FileList result = driveService.files().list()
                    .setQ("not 'me' in owners")
                    .setIncludeItemsFromAllDrives(true)
                    .setSupportsAllDrives(true)
                    .setSpaces("drive,appDataFolder")
                    .setCorpora("allDrives")
                    .execute();
```

Alternatively I used `setQ("sharedWithMe")` with no success

The code works for files in the readers Drive account (only created and owned by the reader) when I remove setQ completely or set it to a mime-type of some sort

Comment: and read by other user accounts  <-- on google drive or though your app?

Comment: Yes, only using my app installed on diferent devices

Comment: I wonder if you can use service account with android

Comment: As far as I understand it may be used however looks like quite a bit of a hassle to do it. Moreover, while I do not know my issue is a limitation the API may have by using API keys, like it does now, using service account sounds ...... not promissing.I will do it if I have to but not before checking all the leads on the path I am on

Comment: I checked all the leads already :) .. service account may be the only option

Answer (score 0):

First let me say I am NOT an android developer, i do however know the google api java client library.  I do not know if this works in andorid or not and would love to hear if it does.

What you are looking for is something called a service account.  Service accounts are like dummy users. If you share a directory with a service account then the service account will have access to this directory without having to authorize a user to access it.

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new 
FileInputStream("MyProject-1234.json"))
.createScoped(Collections.singleton(SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN));
```

[How to create service account credetials.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asrCdWFrF0A)  just remember to enable the google drive api under library.

Comment: Actually the implementation an use of a service account was easy - got scared with some comments found.

Now I tried 2 approaches:

1.

- create the app folder from user1@gmail.com

- create app folder permission type user role writer for the serviceAccount

- upload the file from serviceAccount DriveInstance to the app folder (set parent to folder id from prev step) and *I get the error code 400: **You cannot share this item because it has been flagged as inappropriate** *

Comment: And 2:
- create the app folder from user1@gmail.com
- create app folder permission type user role writer for the serviceAccount
- upload the file from user1@gmail.com and set file permission type user , role writer to my serviceAccount (it is already inherited from the parent folder but ...)
- share the file with userIWantToRead@gmail.com from user1@gmail.com app
- read files from the app of user1@gmail.com, using serviceAccount DriveInstance and does not show anything

Comment: for 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74103726/1841839   <--- try this anwser.

Comment: read files from the app of user1@gmail.com, using serviceAccount DriveInstance and does not show anything  Well that definatly not going to work.  You need to be authorized as user1@gmail.com to see user1's data, the service account can only list what it has access to.

Comment: but the service account has writer permission on the app folder and files generated and uploaded by the user1@gmail.com....

Comment: tried with other files types and managed to upload some with a service account instance of Drive class - it was displaying created by 'serviceAccountEmail@gmail.com'. Deleted everything to start from scratch and now I get the same error, on these types too 'flagged as inappropriate'. As far as I see I could upload files after a whi;e after encountered the error so, I assume, there is some sort of review of the files a service account is uploading, and as soon as you upload other types, uploads are not approved till the next review. Will try again tomorrow

Comment: Think of a service account as a dummy user.  When the service account uploads the file its uploaded by the service account it is then owner of the file.  Granting other users access to the file will be needed unless your using a google workspace account and configure delegation.   'flagged as inappropriate'  what type of file are you uploading?

Comment: The service account is actually another user, but virtual or headless - name it as you will, with an existing email so it is to be treated as such- needs permissions and everything that you would do for any other user

Comment: I can confirm that, in my case, files uploaded with the service account appear in the user1@gmail.com after about 24 hours of being labeled as inappropriate - why it is like that would be interesting to know

Comment: what the file type is that is being flagged as inappropriate would also be interesting

Comment: any file type is flagged this way and  after 24 hours released. My app is not published yet, could it be a reason?!

Comment: it could be but if it is its new I havent seen this before TBH you have me stumped.  I have pinged someone at google for the fun of it.